# If $H \triangleleft G$ and $|G/H|=m$, show that $x^m \in H$ for $\forall x \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

> If $H \triangleleft G$ and $|G/H|=m$, show that $x^m \in H$ for $\forall x \in G$.

My attempt is: since $|G/H|=\frac{|G|}{|H|}=m$, we have $x^{|G|}=x^{m|H|}=e$, then I stuck here. Can anyone guide me ?

Comment: The quotient group $G/H$ has order $m$. In a group of order $m$, we have $x^m=e$ for all $x$. Now in this case, replace $x$ by $xH$ and $e$ by $H$.

Comment: More generally, your result holds as long as $|G:H|=m$. For otherwise, there is $x\in G\setminus H$ such that $o(x)>m$. By counting the number of cosets of $H$, you will find that $\langle H,x\rangle$ will give a group that have larger size than $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $(xH)^m=H$, it follows that $x^mH=H$, and thus that $x^m\in H$.

Answer (score 1):

Your given that $H \triangleleft |G/H| = m.\,$ Hence, for every $\,x\,$ in a group of order of order $m$, $x^m = e$.  
For the group $\,G/H\,$, this means that $\,(xH)^m = H\,$ for all $x \in G.\;\;$ Why?

But as $\,H\,$ is normal in $\,G,\;$ $(xH)^m = H \quad\implies\quad x^mH = eH = H\quad \implies x^m \in H$.